# Google Maps not Showing with div background-color Set

Tags: css, google-maps, background-color

I've got an external style sheet with the following rule:

```
div{background-color:#FFF;}
```

Which prevents my Google Map from displaying. If I take out the above rule the map displays fine. But I would rather not have to set all my divs to have a white background individually.

I'm looking for a way to cancel/reset the div rule so the map will show.

I've tried all of the following, without success:

```
div:not(#mapdiv){background-color:#FFF;}

#mapdiv{background-color:transparent;}

#mapdiv{background-color:none;}

#mapdiv{background:none;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/James2015/mj7ob3ow/) to illustrate this problem:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused not my `#mapdiv`, but with it's children divs (where `div{background-color:#FFF;}` is applied).

Try resetting `background-color` of `#mapdiv` and its children to `initial` state:

```
#mapdiv * {background-color: initial;}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mj7ob3ow/8/

Comment: Thanks that worked great but not in Internet Explorer found: #map * {background-color:transparent;} Got it to work in IE too.